# vue mpa fails to compile when adding css to <style> tags

Tags: css, vue.js

I have an MPA app, where vue.js is used as a part of the application.  I have a very simple test set up, here:

1. relevant parts of my template

```
....
<div id='app-basket-checkout'>
    <h1>Better Be Here</h1>
</div>
....
```

2. pageBasketCheckout.js (essentially my app.js)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import AppBasketCheckout from './BasketCheckout.vue'
import './dummyScss.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    render: h => h(AppBasketCheckout)
}).$mount('#app-basket-checkout')
```

3. component

```
<template>
<div id="app-basket-checkout">
    {{msg}}
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'AppBasketCheckout',
    components: {

    },
    data() {
        return {
            msg: 'Hello'
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

So the above code renders just fine in my front end. I end up with an extra `div` that has hello printed inside, well done.

However when I add css to the style tag:

```
<template>
<div id="app-basket-checkout">
    {{msg}}
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'AppBasketCheckout',
    components: {

    },
    data() {
        return {
            msg: 'Hello'
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
</style>
```

This produces this error in chrome:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './BasketCheckout.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=2711cf65&scoped=true&lang=css&'
    at webpackMissingModule (VM45512 BasketCheckout.vue:4)
    at eval (VM45512 BasketCheckout.vue:4)
    at Module../src/BasketCheckout.vue (pageBasketCheckout.bundle.js:40)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.bundle.js:4312)
    at eval (pageBasketCheckout.js:3)
    at Module../src/pageBasketCheckout.js (pageBasketCheckout.bundle.js:29)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.bundle.js:4312)
    at checkDeferredModulesImpl (index.bundle.js:4453)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (index.bundle.js:4435)
    at pageBasketCheckout.bundle.js:9
```

Again this error only happens when adding css to the component.  Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const glob = require('glob')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'uniquesite/uniquesite'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        index: {
            import: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/index.js'],
            // dependOn: ['babel'],
        },
        pageProductDetails: {
            import: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/pageProductDetails.js'],
            dependOn: ['index'],
        },
        pageBasketCheckout: {
            import: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/dummyScss.scss', './src/pageBasketCheckout.js'],
            dependOn: ['index']
        }
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'uniquesite/uniquesite/static/uniquesite/js/'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery",
            'jquery-ui': "jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js",
            boostrap: "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader'
        },{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'vue-style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
};
```

You'll note I've also tried importing a dummy `.css` file to ensure the style loader works, as I've seen one more SO question with a similar problem that solved it that way.  That didn't work for me however.

**Update 1**

My current thinking is that the problem has to be happening in the VueLoaderPlugin.  That plugin is reponsible for splitting the script into distinct parts for template, logic, and style.  It looks like the style is not actually making it into the bundle.  See below.

```
"use strict";
eval(
    "__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
    /* harmony import */ 
    var _BasketCheckout_vue_vue_type_template_id_2711cf65___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(
        /*! ./BasketCheckout.vue?vue&type=template&id=2711cf65& */ 
        \"./src/BasketCheckout.vue?vue&type=template&id=2711cf65&\"
    );
    /* harmony import */ 
    var _BasketCheckout_vue_vue_type_script_lang_js___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(
        /*! ./BasketCheckout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& */ 
        \"./src/BasketCheckout.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&\"
    );
    Object(function webpackMissingModule() { 
        var e = new Error(
            \"Cannot find module './BasketCheckout.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&'\"
        ); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; 
        throw e; 
    }());
    /* harmony import */ 
    var _node_modules_vue_loader_lib_runtime_componentNormalizer_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(
        /*! !../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer.js */ 
        \"../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer.js\"
    );
    /* normalize component */
    var component = (
        0,_node_modules_vue_loader_lib_runtime_componentNormalizer_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default
    )(
        _BasketCheckout_vue_vue_type_script_lang_js___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default,
        _BasketCheckout_vue_vue_type_template_id_2711cf65___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.render,
        _BasketCheckout_vue_vue_type_template_id_2711cf65___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.staticRenderFns,
        false,
        null,
        null,
        null)

    /* hot reload */
    if (false) { var api; }
    component.options.__file = \"src/BasketCheckout.vue\"
    /* harmony default export */ 
    __webpack_exports__[\"default\"] = (component.exports);

    //# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/BasketCheckout.vue?"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Scoped CSS rules only apply to the current component (and its child components' root nodes).

You are mounting your Vue instance at **#app-basket-checkout**, which is already inside a `<body>` element.

You can style `<body>`, but do it using a global stylesheet that is imported in your **app.js**, not a subcomponent.

Alternatively, you can apply a class-based style at a low level node within your Vue instance and likely deliver your desired styles.